# Java regex and/or string magic to extract IDs from String

Tags: java, regex, json, string

I have a Java app that is hitting a 3rd party RESTful web service that is returning the following JSON:

```
{"fizz":
    {"widgets":
        [
            {
                "widget_id":"295874"
            },
            {
                "widget_id":"295873"
            },
            {
                "widget_id":"295872"
            }
        ],
        "otime":1361993756
    },
    "resp":"ok"
}
```

Normally I would use GSON or Genson to map this back to a Java POJO, but this is the only area of the code where I have to do this and I want to be lazy here ;-).

I'm trying to come up with a nifty method that extracts the 3 `widget_id` values (`,` and `` `) and returns them as a ``List`:

```
public List<Long> extractIdsFromJson(String json) {
    // Can I solve this with a regex perhaps?
}
```

Not sure what the right approach is - regex, replaceAll, something else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// untested
public List<Long> extractIdsFromJson(String json) {
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\"widget_id\":\"?(\\d+)\"?").matcher(json);
    while (matcher.find())
        list.add(Long.valueOf(matcher.group(1)));
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Being lazy here will just bite you in the long run.  Parse the JSON and extract the values that way; the 'effort' involved will be less, the code will be more understandable, and future code maintainers will not curse your name.

Comment: When you say "parse the JSON", you mean like using some kind of `Scanner`/`StringTokenizer` combo?

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys that means, use a JSON parsing library

Comment: Use GSON/Jackson/whatever.  It will save you lots of pain.  For example if the widget_id comes back without quotes, which is perfectly valid JSON, a simple regex will fail whereas the parser will be fine with it.

Comment: @jgm it's not a perfectly valid JSON if there are no quotes around the `widget_id` key. It does bite back, however, if the value becomes a number.

Comment: Yep meant the value not the key (obviously, as that's a number in the example :))

Comment: @jgm note that a parser will report a different data type in such a case. Could that matter?

Comment: who knows?  Best to set up the object being deserializing in to properly and all these issues vanish.  Beats string parsing :)

Answer (score 3):

If you like being lazy. Here is the solution. I hope you know whatever entails your choice of solving the problem with regex:

- It doesn't check for the structure of the JSON. You ignore the fact that the JSON may be malformed and just blindly extract the data.
- It works here since you want a property whose value is not an `Object` or `Array`.

RAW regex:

```
"widget_id"\s*:\s*"(\d+)"
```

In literal string:

```
"\"widget_id\"\\s*:\\s*\"(\\d+)\""
```

Use the regex above with `Matcher` loop:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"widget_id\"\\s*:\\s*\"(\\d+)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: "returns them as a list", not "prints them out". Easy fix, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak: The printing is just to show how to do it. The rest OP can adapt to his needs.