# split string to parts by regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to split string to parts by regex.
String is: `AA2 DE3` or `AA2` and I need this `2`.

```
String code = "AA2 DE3";
String[] parts = code.split("^(AA(\\d)+){1}( )?(\\w*)?$");
```

and here length of `parts` is 0.
I tried

```
String[] parts = code.split("^((AA){1}(\\d)+){1}( )?(\\w*)?$");
```

but also 0.

It looks like wrong regex. Although it works fine in PHP.

**edit**

In fact I need to get the number after "AA" but there may be additional word after it.

Comment: You want the result to be an array containing the single string `2`?

Comment: Why `split`?... The simple regex `AA(\d+)` returns the number that appears after `AA`.

Comment: Because split expects regex as param: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Use Matcher loop like this one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136209/java-regex-and-or-string-magic-to-extract-ids-from-string/15136292#15136292

Comment: @koral If it expects regex doesn't mean that you have to use it always.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun - how should I use regex suggested in first comment? Please note the other part of parsed string which is optional

Comment: @koral What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun I edited my question to answer you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to extract the number and don't care to validate the rest:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^AA(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(code);

String id = null;

if (matcher.find()) {
    id = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Note that I rewrite `(\d)+` to `(\d+)` to capture all the digits. When there are more than one digit, your regex captures only the last digit.

If you want to keep your validation:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^AA(\\d+) ?\\w*$");
```

Answer (score 0):

With `String.split`, the regex specifies what goes in-between the parts. In your case, your regex matches the entire string, so there is nothing else, hence it returns nothing.

If you want to *match* this regex, use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(AA(\\d)+){1}( )?(\\w*)?$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(code);
if(!matcher.matches()) {
    // the string doesn't match your regex; handle this

} else {
    String part1 = matcher.group(1);
    String part2 = matcher.group(2);
    // repeat the above line similarly for the third and forth groups

    // do something with part1/part2/...
}
```

Comment: It is going to throw an IllegalStateException in your 3rd line. You need to call `find()` or `matches()` also works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like `String#split()` to handle the Pattern/Matcher for you, you can use:

```
String[] inputs = { "AA2 DE3", "AA3", "BB45 FG6", "XYZ321" };
    try {
        for (String input : inputs) {
            System.out.println(
                    input.split(" ")[0].split("(?=\\d+$)", 2)[1]
                );
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.err.println("Input format is incorrect.");
    }
}
```

***Output :***

```
2
3
45
321
```

If the input is guaranteed to start with `AA`, you can also use

```
System.out.println(
    input.split(" ")[0].split("(?<=^AA)")[1]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed better to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` APIs for this.

This is purely from academic purpose in case you must use `String#split` only. You can use this lookbehind based regex for `split`:

```
(?<=AA\\d{1,999}) *
```

**Code:**

```
String[] toks = "AA2 DE3".split( "(?<=AA\\d{1,999}) *" ); // [AA2, DE3]
```

OR

```
String[] toks = "AA2".split( "(?<=AA\\d{1,999}) *" ); // [AA2]
```

Comment: Off-Topic: Hi, long time :) Remember? I'm gonna add you on Twitter.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: How are you? Yes pls add me and I will readily accept it.

Comment: I'm good. See you around then, and it's time SO implements some kind of messaging!